# Laravel Sail Carbon\Exceptions\UnitNotConfiguredException

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have a rather esoteric issue. I just upgraded a L9 project to L10 and when I try to log in I am greeted with the message:

```
Carbon\Exceptions\UnitNotConfiguredException

Unit microseconds have no configuration to get total from other units.
```

I have narrowed it down to the Sleep class in Illuminate\Support where a Carbon interval object is being created and the class wants to add microseconds to it. After trying to fix this for several hours now I have simply given up because I can't pinpoint where the actual problem is coming from.

Now the interesting part is: If I deploy this app to my server everything works fine. This only happens in sail and I don't know why.

Here's a link to the entire rendered error page: https://helloo.it/stack-trace.html

Comment: Is there a stack trace that shows what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes and I went through the whole thing which is how I figured out it's happening in the Sleep class. In regards to Carbon it just ends up in line 2591 of this file: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/CarbonInterval.php

Comment: Can you show the stack trace, please?

Comment: I provided a URL for the error page that I am getting.

Comment: Is your server using Debian? The plain, default Sail is using 'Ubuntu 20' as its base, last time I checked. What you can do is change the Dockerfile to reflect your server OS, it might resolve the problem

Comment: The server is AlmaLinux but I think the regular sail boiler plate should be able to handle simple authentication as it does with many other projects.